# C++ Reference initialization

Tags: c++, reference

I'm confused with the reference initialization in C++.
Normally reference should be initialized when it is declared but I found that when it is a class member reference is declared without being initialized.

It is a special case?

What is the correct rule?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Because they're initialized by member initializer list.

Comment: _"but I found that when it is a class member reference is declared without being initialized.It is a special case?"_ Evidence?

Comment: Looks like a [trainwreck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LpCIiwarOk) for me.

Comment: @Walidix If you are still interested in an answer I have posted mine her: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954870/when-a-c-reference-should-be-intialized/38954877#38954877

Comment: You mix up the three related concepts of *declaration*, *definition* and *initialization*. A declaration is just telling the compiler "this symbol exits, and have that type". A definition is where the symbol is actually defined, where the compiler will create something. Lastly initialization can be done when defining a variable (like `int a = 5;`) but it's also what happens when a class constructor is called. Member variables in classes are only *declarations*, and their definitions needs to be *initialized* by the constructor.

Comment: You dont really need a constructor to initiazlize a reference, following is a valid code: `struct X { int tt; int& mri = tt; } xp;`

Comment: @mvidelgauz Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Walidix It seems to be closed now, unfortunatelly. If you managed to read it and it did put at least some light for you, I am happy )))

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear at all, and @JoachimPileborg's comment is exactly the right answer.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg thank you for your answer

Comment: @mrtnj Not all compilers allow to do that. VS2012 doesn't (just checked). Is this form supported by standard?

Comment: @mvidelgauz http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ compiles it - its probably VS2015

Comment: @mrtnj Maybe, I tried it in desktop 2012. Still wondering what standard says about it but didn't have time to search yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rule still applies, reference as member variable you have to initialize in constructor-s initilization list. Example:

```
class X {
public:
    X(int& ri) : mri(ri) {}
    // X()  {} // ERROR! no explicit initialization of mri
    int& mri; 
};

int main() {
    int i;
    X x(i);
}
```

without initilizing it you will get compiler error.

---

(I decided to sum up other good clarifications from comments to make this answer more usefull)

According to standard 8.5.3/3(emphasis mine ) :

> The initializer can be omitted for a reference only in a parameter declaration (8.3.5), in the declaration of
>   a function return type, ***in the declaration of a class member within its class definition (9.2)***, and where the
>   extern specifier is explicitly used.

So the following code is only definition of `struct X` where `mri` variable is only declared.

```
struct X {  
   int &mri; // declaration of mri (ERROR if you define variable of this struct)
};
```

Utill you create (define) an object of type X, compiler will not show any error. When you write:

```
int main() {
    X x; // error, `x.r` is not bound to any object
}
```

compiler will complain, this is because you have defined `x` and this is where you must also bind x.r to some object. The only place where you can do it is in constructors initialization list.

You may notice also that compiler will mark (among others) default constructor as deleted when you add a reference as non static data member.

Comment: What's the down-vote for??? This answer is correct!!! (I was just about to post more or less the same answer BTW).

Comment: Let the OP clarify 1st, before shooting into the dark please. The right reaction is a close vote (and a comment maybe.) Don't encourage asking off-topic questions here please.

Comment: OP-s confusion might be from the fact that `int& mri; ` looks like non initialized reference.But I am just guessing.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Down-voting this answer certainly qualifies under the 'shooting into the dark' category more than this answer does (and if you're the user who took that action, then you're pretty much contradicting yourself in the manner of doing so).

Comment: @barakmanos I want to see a clear question post in 1st place. Otherwise it's not useful for long time research at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How does that justify the choice of down-voting the answer **instead of the question**?

Comment: @barakmanos I down and close voted the question at 1st place of course!

Comment: @sergej Thank you for your answer

Comment: @mrtnj Thank you for your answer